# Symfony 3.3 Update - Argument 5 passed to FrameworkBundle Translator must be of the type array, object given,

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

I just updated from 3.2.9 to 3.3.2

receiving the following error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 5 passed to Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Translation\Translator::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in /dev/shm/appname/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 4100 and defined
```

[image]

No idea where to start looking and what files are needed further to help you to investigate my issue. The stracktrace brings me on the trace of dependency injection.. what breaking change in Symfony 3.3 did I miss?

Comment: It's a class from cache. Have you tried with `cache:clear --env=dev`?

Comment: same.. 

`$ php bin/console cache:clear --env=dev
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException' with message 'Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 5 passed to Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Translation\Translator::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in /dev/shm/appname/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 4100 and defined' in /var/www/backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Translation/Translator.php:59
Stack trace:`

Comment: Try to manually delete `/dev/shm/appname/cache/dev` directory.

Comment: was also my first thought. already did this. still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by removing the lexik translator bundle from the script as it my not be ready for 3.3.x. Then clear cache files again.

Comment: thanks for the insight. Also found it here: https://github.com/lexik/LexikTranslationBundle/issues/258

Comment: This bundle's `composer.json`  says: `"symfony/framework-bundle": "~2.8|~3.0"` so you are already lucky that it's working for you with Symfony 3.2. ;-)